# Go to other ViewController by tapping cell in TableView in Xib file without segue

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone help me how to go to other ViewController by tapping cell in TableView in Xib file without segue.

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("\(indexPath.row)")
        let user = projectDetail.users[indexPath.row] as UserInvitedObject
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let userRightDetailVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserRightDetailViewController") as! UserRightDetailViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(userRightDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

But it is not compiled.

Comment: the compiler normally does tell you *why* it fails to compile your code. What  does it tell *you*?

Comment: I set the debug in it, but it is not compiled at this debug line.

Comment: do you understand the difference between compile time errors, runtime errors and simply unexpected behavior? Since you can *run* the code, there is no compile time error, since it apparently does not crash, there is no runtime error. So what really is going on is that it *does not work as intended*, correct!?

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller / tabbar controller or you just simply want to transition to this new view?

Comment: I just want to transition to the other viewcontroller, no navigation controller and tabbar controller

Comment: Can you post the code that is not compiled?

Comment: The above code is not compiled. When I tap on a cell in table view, it's not go to the debug line.

Comment: Voting to close the question sine you are ignoring the comment explaining contradictions at what you are saying.

Comment: when you tap any row, does indexpath.row print message is written to console log?

Comment: Then does your class conform to UITableViewDelegate protocol. have you set the delegate property?

Comment: Yes, I already set it. That why the code run well. But the code above is not compiled

Answer (score 0):

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(userRightDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is wrong - UIViewController does not have a window reference - it's view has.

So you have to do change it to:

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(userRightDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or you can just present it from the current controller:

```
self.presentViewController(userRightDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The table view is not inside the viewcontroller, it is in a xib file.

Comment: So, this code is not in a controller, it is in the table view itself. At least tell us what error you are receiving.